# Performance implications of string#gsub chains?

Tags: ruby, regex, coding-style

Are there any performance implications of a chain of .gsub and/or .sub methods on a string in Ruby?

For example, here's an example of a method from the Rails source that creates an alt tag for images. It removes the file extension and digest (if any).

```
def image_alt(src)
  File.basename(src, '.*').sub(/-[[:xdigit:]]{32}\z/, '').capitalize
end
```

In my app, I want it to change underscores or hyphens to a space, so I want to add a `gsub` method at the end:

```
def image_alt(src)
  File.basename(src, '.*').sub(/-[[:xdigit:]]{32}\z/, '').gsub(/(_|-)/, ' ').capitalize
end
```

Does that raise red flags with regard to performance or style?

Comment: From the standpoint of maintenance, I'd argue more regexes with each one being smaller, is better than a single gargantuan regex.  As far as speed, I'm not sure.

Comment: Try it both ways and measure performance.  Or write a small test program and compare the implementations.  Real world performance problems are usually not where you expect them to be, so don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: Ruby includes the Benchmark class, which makes it easy to find answers to this sort of question. Read through the examples, write some tests and post your results here so everyone else will learn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
str.tr('-_', ' ')
```

is worth considering ([doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-tr))

Comment: For reference, see my comment below re: Benchmark performance of `string#tr` vs. `string#gsub` with regex.

Comment: One thing to know about string#tr is that it cannot add characters to a string, only replace. So if you need to increase the size of your string, you must use .sub or .gsub.

Answer (score 1):

When the matches of the regexes in the chain are not supposed to overlap, then running them within a conditional under a single [`StringScanner`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html) iteration while outputting the result into a [`StringIO`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) may improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had an issue with it. I use a number `gsub` calls in a couple of my programs and I have not had an issue with performance,. I wouldn't worry about it from a performance stand point. As far as style, I guess that is personal preference.  Personally I try to avoid regex at all cost. But that is just me.

Comment: So then would you say `.gsub('_', ' ').gsub('-', ' ')`?

Comment: @nickvoxdotme `.tr('-_',' ')` is worth considering. ([doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-tr))

Comment: Yes. Using Benchmark, `tr` is roughly twice as fast as `gsub` with a regex, and almost 3 times as fast as two gsub methods chained. @steenslag, care to add that as an answer?

Comment: Using `tr` is a great way to go when replacing characters like this.